# How to kill/reset exisiting tcp connection using python?

Tags: python, linux, tcp

```
     [root~]# netstat -an | grep 443

     tcp       54      0 10.2.2.13:54589          10.1.1.6:443             CLOSE_WAIT  

     tcp        0      0 10.3.1.3:51701           56.92.145.175:443            ESTABLISHED 

     tcp        0      0 :::4443                     :::*                        LISTEN      

     tcp        0      0 :::443                      :::*                        LISTEN      

      unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     34436947 

      unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     34436946 

      unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    34436945
```

Question: Want to reset following connection via python module/script ?

```
      tcp        0      0 10.3.1.3:51701           56.92.145.175:443              ESTABLISHED
```

I have used tcpkill but is there a pythonic way to handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps : https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['/sbin/tcpkill','-i',interface_name,'-9','ip',ip_address])
```